# xunicode&xeCJK TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \begin{document}

Tags: xetex, moderncv, xecjk, chinese

I am making my Chinese resume with moderncv, but I meet some problem. I spent the whole afternoon in searching for some solution but they didn't work. I am using texlive2019 in win10.
please help. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\name 啊啊
\begin{document}
    啊啊啊
\end{document}
```

Moreover, I got some warnings, like these:

```
Unknown slot number of character(microtype) `\`A'(microtype) in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list(microtype) `microtype.cfg/376(protrusion)'.
Unknown slot number of character(microtype) `\'A'(microtype) in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list(microtype) `microtype.cfg/376(protrusion)'.
Unknown slot number of character(microtype) `\^A'(microtype) in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list(microtype) `microtype.cfg/376(protrusion)'.
```

I think it's the problem of xunicode or xeCJK. And I make sure that my microtype is updated.

It didn't work on overleaf.com.

Update: When I don't use xunicode, and it can work. But when I use itemize in document, I meet another problem:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\name {啊}{}
\begin{document}
    \section{}
    \cventry{}{}{}{}{}{
    \begin{itemize}
            \item 啊
    \end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

And I get some information like this:

```
name = umvs, rootname = umvs, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Cannot find font umvs in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf umvs.mf The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexmf Cannot find umvs.mf . I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf. ps2pk cannot be used. I try gsftopk. gsftopk.exe umvs 600 gsftopk cannot be used. Next I try ttf2pk. ttf2pk.exe -q umvs 600 ttf2pk failed. Finally I try hbf2gf. hbf2gf.exe -q -p umvs 600 All trials failed. kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 umvs The command name is C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\mktexpk kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log. xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output... No output PDF file written.
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the xunicode package. It is obsolete now.

This here compiles (but I don't know how the name should be correctly set):

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\name{啊啊}{}
\begin{document}
    啊啊啊
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! But I met another problem when add itemize in document. I have updated my problem. Please help.

Comment: Probably you don't have marvosym fonts.
If you have it, the following commands show full path
of corresponding file:
`kpsewhich umvs.tfm`

`kpsewhich morvosym.pfb`

`kpsewhich morvosym.map`

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!! It worked!!!!!!!